# The vowel “e” changes to the “a”

Tags: etymology

In the German language articles and pronouns look similar, e.g. "s**ie**"/"d**ie**","**er**"/"d**er**". Are the letter "e" in the word "es" and the letter "a" in the word "das" a sound shift, by analogy with d**e**nken -> d**a**chte?

Comment: I don't think so: If this was the case, you could not explain why the word is "*sie*" and not "*ie*".

Comment: In some dialects, people say in fact *des* instead of *das*.

Comment: Others say *dit* "das", correlating perhaps not just by chance with English *it*.

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort *»er«* ist nicht mit *»der«* verwandt, wohl aber sind *»er«* und *»es«* Geschwister.

### er, es

Die deutschen Pronomen *»er«* und *»es«* aber auch das englische *»it«* und auch das niederdeutsche *»et«* sind verwandt mit dem altindischen *»idam«* (deutsch: »es«) und dem lateinischen *»id«* (»derjenige, dieser«) und dem ebenfalls lateinischen *»is«* (»dasjenige, dieses«)

Andere Formen sind:

- Mittelhochdeutsch: *er, eʒ*
- Altsächsisch: *it* (für beide Geschlechter)
- Althochdeutsch: *ir, er* bzw. *iʒ, eʒ*
- Altgotisch: *is* (=»er«) und *ita* (=»es«)
- Litauisch: *jis* (für beide Geschlechter)
- Altirisch: *ē* (=»er«)

---

### sie

- Gotisch: *si*
- Althochdeutsch: *sī̌*
- Altsächsisch: *thiu, siu, sia*

---

### die

- Althochdeutsch: *thiu*
- Altsächsisch: thie
- Mittelniederländisch: *diu*

---

### der

- Althochdeutsch: *ther*
- Altsächsisch: thē̌
- Mittelniederländisch: *dē*

Comment: ich glaube nicht, dass wir mit der indischen Sprache verwandt sind ;)

Comment: @äüö: Wir nicht, aber die deutsche Sprache schon. Beides sind **indo**germanische Sprachen. Siehe auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indogermanische_Sprachen

Comment: indo hat nichts mit Indien zu tun

Answer (score -2):

No, in the standard German language you really differ between "e" and "a".

For example:

1. [lenken](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lenken) (to steer/to direct) -> l**e**nkte
2. [senken](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/senken) (to reduce) -> s**e**nkte

> But in some dialects (bavarian for example) you really could say **"des"** instead if **"das"**. So you can keep that as mnemonic for  **"es->"das"** if you think of Bavarians ^^

Comment: vowel alternation, like in "sinkt, sank, gesunken" or En. "drink, drank, drunk", is an old Germanic feature. There are different 3-way series that I don't recall exactly. You cannot just say "No", lol.

Comment: Well, I understood his question als a way of asking "Is it a general rule"... And in that case the answer is No (because... And you delivered the evidence yourselfe... It just isn´t.